# Nested JSON SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I checked this tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/nested-json/4018 to fix a nested json issue.

My JSON source has changed from

```
[{"title":"title","link":"...","description":"..."....
```

to

```
{"items":[{..
```

my original struct was like this

```
struct Novitads: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id = UUID()
    public var title: String
    public var pubDate: String
    public var description: String
    public var link: String
    public var image: URL
//    public var pubDate: String
}
```

now I added:

```
struct News: Codable {
    var items: [Novitads]
}
```

which is consistent with the article with the solution.

Unfortunately, my fetch class now fails:

```
class FetchNovitads: ObservableObject {

@Published var Novitadss = [Novitads]()
@Published var selectedCode: String?
public lazy var selectC: Double = 0.1

let x: Double = 21.25
func refresh() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://testapi-")!
    print (url)
    print (selectedCode)
    print (selectC)
    
    selectC = Double(selectedCode ?? "0") ?? 0.1
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
        do {
            if let NovitadsData = data {
           
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: NovitadsData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.Novitadss = decodedData
                }
            } else {
                print("No data")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

more precisely on  `self.Novitadss = decodedData`
Cannot assign value of type 'News' to type '[Novitads]' this did not occur when I used the previous json structure (not nested) so had no need for the News struct.

I am sure there is something trivial I am missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decode `News` you have to assign the `items` array to `Novitadss`

```
self.Novitadss = decodedData.items
```

And please name properties with starting lowercase letter

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
self.Novitadss = decodedData.items
```

and now by iterating, you can fetch the properties inside this with respect to index value.